# Move from final 1.3 rc to 1.3.0 - <select> option problems after <select> bug fixes made in the move

Tags: angularjs

My application has this HTML:

```
<select id="contentTypeSelect"
   ng-change="home.configChanged(true)"
   ng-model="ctrl.configService.admin.contentTypeId"
   ng-options="item.id as item.name for item in content"></select>
```

Here is the value of content:

```
var content = 
[{"id":0,"name":"*"},
 {"id":1,"name":"Menu"},
 {"id":2,"name":"Service"},
 {"id":3,"name":"Help"},
 {"id":4,"name":"Product"},
 {"id":5,"name":"Version"},
 {"id":6,"name":"Exam"},
 {"id":7,"name":"Track"}]
```

My problem is that it creates a select with a blank entry:

```
<select id="contentTypeSelect" 
   ng-change="home.configChanged(true)" 
   ng-model="ctrl.configService.admin.contentTypeId" 
   ng-options="item.id as item.name for item in content" 
     class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid">
   <option value="? string: ?">
   </option><option value="0" selected="selected">*</option>
   <option value="1">Menu</option>
   <option value="2">Service</option>
   <option value="3">Help</option>
   <option value="4">Product</option>
   <option value="5">Version</option>
   <option value="6">Exam</option>
   <option value="7">Track</option>
</select>
```

Can someone help explain to me why this line is in the HTML:

```
<option value="? string: ?">
```

Here is how I am populating the select data:

```
self.content = results[2];
self.configService.admin.contentTypeId = self.content[0].id;
```

First I populate the data in self.content and then I set the modal to the id of the first element of that array.

Note this is only a problem with the production 1.3 release. I am not seeing this problem with that beta.

```
> @license AngularJS v1.3.0-beta.8 // This release is working for me
> @license AngularJS v1.3.0-rc.3   // This release is working for me
> @license AngularJS v1.3.0-rc.5   // This release is working for me
> @license AngularJS v1.3.0        // This release is failing for me
```

I assume now that this change is the result of the following change made between rc5 and the production release:

```
1.3.0 superluminal-nudge (2014-10-13)
Bug Fixes
select:
add basic track by and select as support (addfff3c, #6564)
manage select controller options correctly (2435e2b8, #9418)
```

I will look into this. Hopefully the bug fix did not introduce a new bug that I am facing. Certainly my code now appears to work in all versions prior to 1.3.0

Please note the order that my application works.

a) Open the HTML
b) Get the data for the select list (takes 5 seconds)
c) Populate ng-options
d) Populate ng-model

Could this be a problem related to the bug fix that was added just before the release of 1.3.0 to the  options.  My same code has been working for a year now and suddenly is giving me this problem ONLY with the latest 1.3.0 release.

Comment: Assign a value to your "model" which is in the list of options.

Comment: Could you add a full executable example showing the wrong behavior (maybe on plnkr.co or similar)? Because at the moment I can't reproduce your problem even with v1.3.0.

Comment: @Yoshi - I think Dennis may have already done this but I am not sure how to make his version into a plnkr.co   My code has about 40 select boxes that are populated this way. Every one of these behaves the same. Did you notice the fix that was made to select options just before 1.3.0 release. My code has been working for every version of AngularJS for over a year until this very latest release.

Comment: @marifemac Maybe you can use [this](http://plnkr.co/edit/dm7oHAV7NKti163aEMGN?p=preview) and add parts of your code until it *breaks*?

Comment: @Yoshi - Thank you. One thing I notice about your code. In my application I open the HTML and initially there is no setting for the ng-model value. Then I get data and 5 seconds later I populate the contents and then populate the ng-model. I wonder if the problem is related to the fact that I get data later on in the process rather than immediately as in your example?

Comment: @marifemac That could certainly be the problem! I'll try to implemnt an async assignment.

Comment: @marifemac I updated the [test-code](http://plnkr.co/edit/dm7oHAV7NKti163aEMGN?p=preview), I now can see the *lingering* empty option after the data gets loaded async. Hopefully this will help others to work on the problem. Maybe you can add the link to the plunker in your question, so that it's more visible.

Comment: @marifemac I think I found something. It seems the problem is related to the id `0`. If you pre-select any other value, the problem disappears. If that's the case, I think you should file a [bug-report](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues) with angular.

Comment: @marifemac I think you ran into this known bug: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/9714

Comment: @Yoshi - can you please enter your findings as an answer so I can accept and so others will see that it's a bug. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a known bug with `v1.3.0` (see: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/9714 and https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/9691).

The bug is in someway triggered by an async assignment of `ngOptions` model data and pre-selecting a value with a *falsy* identifier (e.g. `''` or `0`). It can be reproduced as follows:

```js
(function (app, ng) {
  'use strict';

  app.controller('AppCtrl', ['$timeout', function($timeout) {
    var vm = this;

    $timeout(function () {
      vm.content = [
        { id: 0, name: 'A' },
        { id: 1, name: 'B' },
        { id: 2, name: 'C' }
      ];
    }, 1000);
  }]);
}(angular.module('app', []), angular));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0/angular.min.js"></script>
<div data-ng-app="app">
  <!-- wrong behavior -->
  <div data-ng-controller="AppCtrl as app1" data-ng-init="app1.selected = 0;">
    <select
      data-ng-model="app1.selected"
      data-ng-options="item.id as (item.name + ' [' + item.id + ']') for item in app1.content"
      size="4"
    ></select>
  </div>

  <!-- correct behavior -->
  <div data-ng-controller="AppCtrl as app2" data-ng-init="app2.selected = 1;">
    <select
      data-ng-model="app2.selected"
      data-ng-options="item.id as (item.name + ' [' + item.id + ']') for item in app2.content"
      size="4"
    ></select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: In your example this might not be considered as a bug since you set the selected value in ng-init. When ng-init is executed content is not yet set and undefined. So you set the selected item for an not existing list. But when you set the selected property in the timeout call your example works just fine. So your example does not directly resemble the original problem...

Comment: @DenisThomas I only use `ng-init` so that I don't have to copy the whole controller. The problem exists as long as the pre-selected value is `0`, regardless of when it is set. ([in `$timeout`](http://jsbin.com/mirogubeqi/1/), [before `$timeout`](http://jsbin.com/kidiqewipu/1/))

Comment: @DenisThomas The problem even exists in your example code, because it's not the pre-selection that's not working, but rather that there is an empty option even though it shouldn't be there.

Comment: I did some testing with your example and noticed that there are some differences: if 0 or undefined is pre selected the selection gets not updated correctly when selected is set in the timeout function if something other is pre selected (1) the selection gets updated. The empty entry always occurs when 0 should be selected so this might result from a check like if(0) to determine if a selection was made. In your exemple this is obvious, when using the dropdown the empty entry is not directly visible and I didn't notice it was there.

Comment: @DenisThomas Yes, which is basically what is described here: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/9714

Answer (score 0):

This additional option results from no item beeing selected by default. If you set ctrl.configService.admin.contentTypeId to a valid ID from your list of items that one will be selected and you will no longer see this additional option with value ?

So this results from either no selection was defined or there is an error and the selected item can not be determined

**Update:**
I changed the AngularJS version to 1.3 and it still behaves as expected

**Update2:**
Eventually you should propagate the new value of self.configService.admin.contentTypeId by calling $scope.apply()?

**Update3:**
Added an async function for simulating getting data from service.
Without calling $apply() there is no way for Angular to know that any of the $scope values have changed since there are no events which can trigger an update. So you have to tell Angular that you changed some value. You can see this if you remove the $apply() call, then event the simple message text does not get updated.

**Update4:**
Changed setTimeout to $timeout since then $apply() is not required liks Yoshi explained.

**Example:**

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope, $timeout) {
    $scope.status = 'loading...';
    $scope.getData = function () {
        $timeout(function () {
            $scope.selectedItem = 0;
            $scope.content = 
               [{ "id": 0, "name": "*" },
                { "id": 1, "name": "Menu" },
                { "id": 2, "name": "Service" },
                { "id": 3, "name": "Help" }]
            $scope.status = 'Call done!';
        }, 1000);
    };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="MyCtrl" ng-init="getData()">
        <label>Status: {{status}}</label><br/>
        <select ng-model="selectedItem" ng-options="item.id as item.name for item in content"></select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: My code does set the value. I updated the question to show this. I notice your example is using AngularJS 1.2.23. My problem seems to come up one with Angular 1.3 (latest)

Comment: I updated my answer with a few more checks of releases prior to the final 1.3. All work perfectly up until the final 1.3.0 release. I noticed one thing about that release. There were bug fixes for <select> options in that release. I am looking at it now. But as it is so consistent to pass in prior and fail in 1.3.0 I assume it is a result of the "bug fixes".

Comment: I updated my answer with a few more checks of releases prior to the final 1.3. All work perfectly up until the final 1.3.0 release. I noticed one thing about that release. There were bug fixes for <select> options in that release. I am looking at it now. But as it is so consistent to pass in prior and fail in 1.3.0 I assume it is a result of the "bug fixes".

Comment: results is an array of arrays. The data in results[2] is used to populate self.content so a matching data item must exist. It shows as correctly selected in the HTML. The problem is the other <option> item is not being removed correctly.

Comment: @Dennis - I just added a comment to Yoshi. You are populating your data at a different time from me. In my case I download and open the HTML and then after 5-10 seconds I get the data from my remote server and populate the ng-options. Then after that I set the value of the ng-model. I am wondering if 1.3.0 is objecting to the order I do this in and not showing the correct select because of this.

Comment: @marifemac - Ok that is why I would suggest to call .$apply() on the scope after the value of ng-model has been set to notify angular that the DOM has to be updated since the data has changed. As far as I know a call to $apply() is required here to get it working consistently.

Comment: @DenisThomas `$apply` is only ever needed if one reacts to an *outside* events (e.g. jQuery, navigator.geolocation and similar). If only angular is used, $apply should never be required.

Comment: @Yoshi - since the id is a simple field of $scope I don't know how Angular can detect that you have changed its value without calling $apply(). If you know how setting the id can trigger Angular to update the DOM please let me know how this is done.

Comment: @DenisThomas Angular is watching all scope (model) values and if it detects a change the dom (view) is updated. The watchers are triggerd on each digest-cycle, which in turn get's triggerd when *native* angular methods are used (e.g. $timeout, $q and similar). This way $apply is never needed.